# Facebook Graph API(Version 2.3) publish event on a page from CRM plugin/wflow using C#/JS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

In FB Graph API version 1 we had written a plugin and some js which used to push details of our campaign record in CRM to a predefined FB page as an event.

Now in Version 2.3 the publishing endpoint is missing from the GRAPH api.(events)

My questions are

1) Is there a possible way/workaround to achieve the same use-case using Version 2.3
2) Can my client pay Facebook so that they allow us to achieve the same.(publish an event on our company page from CRM)

If I have missed something in the new graph api, do let me know

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly stated the ability to create events has vanished with the introduction of the Graph API v2.0.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#publish

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

I highly doubt there is a workaround, and if, it would be against FB's platform policies IMHO. Also, there is no way to do a "buy-in" as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Tobi,
Thanks for your prompt response, is it possible to publish anything on a page.
I mean can I publish a post on a company page using graph api. Page and page admin both belong to the same company.(all the authentication can be done)